# How to split string and organize in array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to separate these string:

```
var str = '(john) the quick brown (emily) fox jumps over (steam) the lazy dog.'
var str1 = '(john) the quick brown fox jumps over (steam) the lazy dog.'
```

so that the array will look something like this:

```
     john: "the quick brown"
     emily: "fox jumps over"
     steam: "the lazy dog."

and

     john: "the quick brown fox jumps over"
     steam: "the lazy dog."
```

So far I have tried to use the split() and join() functions, but to no avail.

```
var strNew = str.split(' ').join('|');
var johnSplit = strNew.split('(john)');
str = johnSplit;
var emilySplit = str1.split('(emily)');
console.log(johnSplit);
console.log(emilySplit);
```

Comment: `john` should be a name of variable of array or what?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @DominikMatis yea, john is the name of the variable of which the string 'the quick brown' is associated to

Comment: @Taplar it isnt much, but i have updated my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite neatly with a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/PWqDsx/1/), a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
function* split(str) {
  const regex = /\((.*?)\)\s*(.*?)(?=\s*(\(|$))/gm;
  let m;
  while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    yield [m[1], m[2]]
  }
}

const str = `(john) the quick brown (emily) fox jumps over (steam) the lazy dog.`;
const output = Object.fromEntries(split(str))

console.log(output)
console.log(output["john"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below method.

```js
var str = '(john) the quick brown (emily) fox jumps over (steam) the lazy dog.'
var str1 = '(john) the quick brown fox jumps over (steam) the lazy dog.'

function splitAndCreateArray(str) {
    return str.split('(').filter(s => !!s).map(s => s.replace(')', ':'));
}

console.log(splitAndCreateArray(str))
```

If you want your answer to be in JSON, please use the below snippet.

```js
var str = '(john) the quick brown (emily) fox jumps over (steam) the lazy dog.'
var str1 = '(john) the quick brown fox jumps over (steam) the lazy dog.'

function splitAndCreateArray(str) {
return str.split('(').filter(s => !!s).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const [key, value] = curr.split(')');
    acc[key] = value; // Optional: You can use value.trim() to remove the white spaces.
    return acc;
}, {});
}

console.log(splitAndCreateArray(str))
```

Comment: is there a way to make the variable names seperate from the message? like john: "the quick brown"

Comment: You can use JSON instead of array then.

Comment: @Mosukoshide - I have updated my answer to turn the array into a JS object with names as variables

Answer (score 0):

1. Split string into array with `(` elements
2. Remove empty elements
3. Use `reduce` to turn array into JS object
4. Extract variable name using Regular Expression Capture Group

   ```
   const str = '(john) the quick brown fox jumps over (steam) the lazy dog.';
   console.log(
     str
       .split('(')
       .filter(elem => elem)
       .reduce((accum, curr) => {
         const varNameRegex = new RegExp(/(.*)\)/);
         const varName = curr.match(varNameRegex)[1];
         accum[varName] = curr.replace(varNameRegex, '').substring(1);

         return accum;
       }, {})
   );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could split by parentheses and reduce the parts.

```js
var string = '(john) the quick brown (emily) fox jumps over (steam) the lazy dog.',
    result = string
        .split(/[()]/)
        .slice(1)
        .reduce((r, s, i, a) => {
            if (i % 2) r[a[i - 1]] = s.trim();
            return r;
        }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: is there a way to make the variable names seperate from the message? like john: "the quick brown" so that I can do console.log(result["john"]);